# Rewarded more for visiting Pokestops I've never visited before?

Tags: pokemon-go

I visit the same 14 Pokestops every day and get very poor results. I get more potions, revives, and RazzBerries than you can shake a stick at. When I get eggs,  3 out of 4 are 2km eggs. Getting more than 1 *pokeball* is satisfying, and getting a *great pokeball* is thrilling. I've gotta an *ultra pokeball* just once. So, that's how 100 Pokestops per week has gone for me.

Today, I got the chance to visit a Pokestop I've never been to before, and I got 2 *ultra pokeballs* and a 10km egg!

Are all Pokestops treated as the same? Or, will Pokestops you've never visited before give you a chance for better results?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From personal experience, no there does not seem to be a difference. I have a Pokéstop in range of my desk, so I can collect it periodically throughout the day, and there is no pattern to what I receive. Sometimes I get 5 potions, other times I get 3 ultra balls. It is pretty random assortment of different combinations of items received. When I go to different places and collect stuff from Pokéstops there, I notice no difference in what I receive. It is all pretty random, and I have visited Pokéstops over 1000 times.

Comment: Anecdotally: I also have a stop that I can reach from my desk and I feel like I've been getting fewer items recently, but I'm not sure if I'm just imagining it

Comment: @JimMouer I haven't noticed it personally. I still seem to get the same amount of stuff each time.

Comment: It might very well be in my head. I'm just not sure if anything else became more frustrating after the last update

Comment: I remember reading once that more notable landmarks give more items on average, but I can't find it now, and I don't know if it was true.  Some stops do seem like they give more items than others, but it could just be coincidence.

Comment: @Kat, I haven't been to any places that are super notable, such as the Statue of Liberty or anything, so I cannot personally attest to whether they do or not. However, I don't see why they would. Everything I have seen on Pokéstops from what has been datamined suggests only one type of Pokéstop.

Comment: I think I've been getting more regular pokéballs since the recent update, but other than that yes it still feels completely random

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to matter if you have ever visited a Pokestop before, but apparently you *do* get a bonus if you hit 10 unique stops in a row. On the tenth stop, you will get extra items, double xp, and an egg if you have room.

Source: http://otakukart.com/animeblog/2016/08/05/new-way-spinning-poke-stops-gives-double-poke-balls-exp-guaranteed-egg/

I'm not sure how reliable the source is, so if anyone can confirm or deny through their own testing, that'd be helpful. I'll test it too as soon as I get the chance.

Answer (score 0):

The game does not usually give extra rewards for visiting new Pokestops. That is, there is no chance that just visiting a new Stop will give you more items.

However, if you visit 10 unique stops in a row (within 30 minutes), you will be granted [significantly more items and XP](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4w6s8t/10th_pokestop_hack_bonus/) for the last Stop.